# VBA cut/paste after inserting row

Tags: vba, excel

I would really appreciate any help with identifying what's wrong with my VBA code - if I test it, nothing happens to data in the spreadsheet.

I am attempting to take rows which have either two different emails and pull the latter down below the first in a newly-created row (If), or take duplicate emails and delete the latter (ElseIf).

```
Sub email_List()

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value And IsEmpty(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9)) = False Then
        ActiveCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Cut
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 3).Paste

    ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9).Value.Clear

    End If

Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub email_List()
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lLastRow To 2 Step -1

        If ws.Cells(i, 3).Value <> ws.Cells(i, 9).Value And IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 9)) = False Then
            ws.Rows(i + 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            ws.Cells(i, 9).Cut ws.Cells(i + 1, 3)
        ElseIf ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 9).Value Then
            ws.Cells(i, 9).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I had to hard-code the beginning row (4,433) and remove the 1lastrow variable, but this worked! Thank you so, so much!

Comment: `lLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` is finding the last row in column A. May be you want to count column C (`Rows.Count, 3`). Anyway, glad to help.